# how to simulate simple orbiting behaviour in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

My problem lies in weird blinking visible in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jn97Lt4e/2/

```
var addRandomDebris, i, render, satellites, source;

var getRandomFromBetween = function(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};

source = {
  size: 20
};

satellites = [];

addRandomSatellites = function() {
  satellites.push({
    distance: getRandomFromBetween(50, 375),
    size: getRandomFromBetween(2, 6),
    speed: getRandomFromBetween(5, 30),
    angle: getRandomFromBetween(1, 359)
  });
};

i = getRandomFromBetween(32, 64);

while (i-- > 0) {
  addRandomSatellites();
}

render = function(satellites, source) {
  var animateFrames, container, dimensions, svg, timeZero;

  dimensions = {
    width: 800,
    height: 800
  };

  timeZero = Date.now();

  svg = d3.select('#svg')
    .insert('svg')
    .attr('viewBox', '0, 0, 800, 800')
    .attr('class', 'game-planetarium');

  svg.append('circle')
    .attr('r', source.size)
    .attr('cx', dimensions.width * 0.5)
    .attr('cy', dimensions.height * 0.5)
    .attr('class', 'source');

  container = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + dimensions.width * 0.5 + ',' + dimensions.height * 0.5 + ')');

  container.selectAll('g.satellite')
    .data(satellites)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'satellite')
    .each(function(d, i) {
      d3.select(this)
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', d.size)
        .attr('cx', d.distance)
        .attr('cy', 0)
        .attr('class', 'satellite');
    });

  animateFrames = function() {
    var delta = Date.now() - timeZero;

    svg.selectAll('.satellite')
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'rotate(' + d.angle + delta * (d.speed / 10000) + ')';
    });
  };

  d3.timer(animateFrames);
};

(function() {
  render(satellites, source);
})();
```

I am trying to put together a simple d3 based animation, which represents some kind of static center body and a group of satellites oribiting around it.

I have discovered a good example: http://bl.ocks.org/djvanderlaan/4953593 of this, and tried to adjust it to my needs. Unfortunatelly, this weird blinking is ruining the decently working animation, and I have no idea how to debug it.

Also, after longer period of time, the animation becomes less and less fluid.

Can you suggest a better approach or point out the reason for the blinking of the sattelites?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be fixed by switching your timing system from computing the delta between now and the start of the program to now and the last frame:

```
container.selectAll('g.satellite')
    .data(satellites)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'satellite')
    .each(function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this)
            .append('circle')
            .attr('r', d.size)
            .attr('cx', d.distance)
            .attr('cy', 0)
            .attr('class', 'satellite')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + d.angle + ')');
    });

animateFrames = function() {
    var delta = Date.now() - timeZero;
    timeZero += delta;

    svg.selectAll('.satellite')
        .each(function (d) {
            var satellite = d3.select(this);
            var t = d3.transform(satellite.attr("transform"));
            t.rotate += delta * d.speed / 10000;
            satellite.attr("transform", "rotate(" + t.rotate + ")");
        });
};
```

Comment: Seems to be working, thank you. I have also found out that simply setting the transformation to `rotate(' + (d.angle + delta * (d.speed / 10000)) % 360 + ')'` fixes the bizarre degrees the code was outputing - and the errors as well.